# Higher availability for the Remote PowerShell

Tags: powershell, high-availability, winrm

I want to connect to exchange server via remote Powershell. When I connect directly with server URL I am able to create the session. But in the production I have many instances of exchange server

In case there is a problem on one of the machines or we do maintenance, we want to have some resiliency against single-machine outages.

Here is my script :

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$uri='http://<FQDN of Exchange 2013 Client Access server>/PowerShell/'
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $uri -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
Import-PSSession $Session
```

Comment: What is your *actual* question?

Comment: I am asking how to script a failover to another exchange server if one is unavailable or drops